# How to stop Java from blocking my Applet run locally from my Hard Disk?

Tags: java, security, applet, certificate

I created a simple Applet  , It runs well in Eclipse , But when i try to put it in HTML page and run it , I get this error : 
Your security settings have blocked a local application from running. I tried to change my security options from Very High to High (lowest thing there) but not working also , Tried to add the address "C:\Users\me\Desktop\" where my HTML file is located to Java Exception list but it won't accept it , any advice ?

Comment: Why are you learning a dead technology? Oracle has deprecated Applets.

Comment: Of course for my stupid ancient college , This course is on Graphics and they use Java in it .

Comment: *"course for my stupid ancient college"*  Please refer the teacher to [Why CS teachers should **stop** teaching Java applets](http://programmers.blogoverflow.com/2013/05/why-cs-teachers-should-stop-teaching-java-applets/).  *"This course is on Graphics and they use Java in it ."* Java could do graphics outside applets from Java 1.1. The reason that applets were used is because they were considered easier to get from go to working code you could view. That ended a significant time ago.

Comment: Sadly educational system here in Egypt lags the world by dozens of years , I would of course take you advice if choosing the course was my decision, but as i have no choice here and i need to pass the exam , Any workaround for this particular issue ?